# Auto submitting form from client side

Tags: javascript, html

I have Quiz app built on rails. On the server side I am sending a question along with its option to the UI. Currently once the user clicks **Submit** button the data gets created.

What I am trying to do is to set a 30 minutes timer on that page. And I learned that it's not an efficient way to do the timer thing from server side. Hitting server every second or minute sounds in-efficient.

The form looks like this.

```
<form class="new_reply" id="new_reply" action="/quizzes/3/replies" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1ImRYW1w" />

    <label>
  First war of Independence year
</label>
<div class="radio">
    <p>
      <label>
        1947
        <input type="radio" value="22" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][possible_answer_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_possible_answer_id_22" />
        <input type="hidden" value="9" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][question_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_question_id" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        1857
        <input type="radio" value="23" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][possible_answer_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_possible_answer_id_23" />
        <input type="hidden" value="9" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][question_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_question_id" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        1930
        <input type="radio" value="24" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][possible_answer_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_possible_answer_id_24" />
        <input type="hidden" value="9" name="reply[answers_attributes][0][question_id]" id="reply_answers_attributes_0_question_id" />
      </label>
    </p>

</div>

  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Finish quiz" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

I want the `submit` to hit after 30 minutes. Can anybody please help here ?

**js timer**

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the form after 30 minutes with the following JS code

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("new_reply").submit();
}, 1000 * 60 * 30);
```

Have a timestamp on the server side when the timer starts and compare against the timestamp when it is submitted and make sure they are in the correct range.

Comment: This works. I am also trying to display the counter in the top by doing `window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};`. The issue is , the counter starts only after reload the page and not when the page is opened visited. The user is being forced to reload the page again. How can I fix this ?

Comment: can you provide the definition of startTimer also

Comment: Updated the post. Please have a look

Comment: this looks fine apart from you resetting the timer when it becomes 0.